# Varias filas de un join de dos registros

Tags: join

En una unión de dos tablas donde la tabla principal es del tipo: Tabla A

> ```
> A.row_Id, A.link_Id
> ```

y la secundaria es del tipo: Tabla B

> ```
> B.link_Id, B.Valor_a1, B.Valor_a2, B.Valor_b1, B.Valor_b2, B.Valor_c1, 
> B.Valor_c2, B.Valor_d1, B.Valor_d2
> ```

Quiero obtener una tabla con los registros que no sean nulos

```
A.row_Id, B.Valor_a1, B.Valor_a2
A.row_Id, B.Valor_b1, B.Valor_b2
A.row_Id, B.Valor_c1, B.Valor_c2
A.row_Id, B.Valor_d1, B.Valor_d2
```

Es decir, de la segunda tabla quiero obtener hasta cuatro registros (a, b, c, y d) que no sean nulos,ya que puede existir solo a / a y b / a, b y c / a, b, c y d)

No sé cómo. ¿Es posible?
Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], también sería bueno que armes un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida esperada. Etiqueta también la pregunta con el motor de base de datos adecuado. Suerte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por favor ejecuta:

```
SELECT A.row_Id, B.Valor_a1 as valor_1, B.Valor_a2 as valor_2 FROM A JOIN B ON A.link_Id = B.link_Id 
UNION 
SELECT A.row_Id, B.Valor_b1 as valor_1, B.Valor_b2 as valor_2 FROM A JOIN B ON A.link_Id = B.link_Id
UNION 
SELECT A.row_Id, B.Valor_c1 as valor_1, B.Valor_c2 as valor_2 FROM A JOIN B ON A.link_Id = B.link_Id
UNION
SELECT A.row_Id, B.Valor_d1 as valor_1, B.Valor_d2 as valor_2 FROM A JOIN B ON A.link_Id = B.link_Id
```

Me comentas como te fue.

Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto! UNION era lo que me faltaba.  El problema es que a la tabla A tengo otros 8 INNER JOINS y en WHERE tengo 6 condiciones con lo que repetir todo se hace largo, pero funciona. Gracias